# How to use relative references in an ARRAYFORMULA with DSUM

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have a formula:
Total Hours:

```
=DSUM(data!A1:B, "Number of Hours", {"Provider Name";A2})
```

The column A is a dynamic list of all the providers. How do I use an array formula to fill in all the rows that have a provider in column A, using the provider that is in that row in column A?

I tried doing:
Test 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", DSUM(data!$A$1:$B, "Number of Hours", {"Provider Name";A2}), ""))
```

But the A cell does not change. I get the array down the column like I wanted, but it is all for the provider in A2.
I also tried:
Test2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", DSUM(data!$A$1:$B, "Number of Hours", {"Provider Name";A2:A}), ""))
```

But this gives me a sum of all the provider hours in every cell in the column, not just the provider in that row.
I also tried:
Test3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", DSUM(data!$A$1:$B, "Number of Hours", {"Provider Name";INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1, 4))}), ""))
```

But it just does the provider in A2.
What else should I try?
I do not want to copy all the rows every time a new person comes into or leaves  column A.
Here is an example spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aUQ5WHjsvgGU_nZtNLcPTilJDRlOz-Z3prfNbgrJNzw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use DSUM in the way described in the question. Instead of DSUM use QUERY:

`=QUERY(data!A:B,"select A,SUM(B) where A <>'' group by A label SUM(B) 'Total Hours'")`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize query could do that! I thought ArrayFormulas were the answer here as I wanted to perform a function on an array. But this works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use an array formula to fill in all the rows that have a provider in column A, using the provider that is in that row in column A?

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(A1:A)
```

Comment: I added a spreadsheet that should clear things up. This answer just reflects what is in column A and doesn’t perform any summing of the scores in data.